# Change WIDTH of DIVS next to each other on HOVER

Tags: html, css, animation, width

I make **2 divs** with different images **next to each other**. 
One will be called "**Land**" and the other "**Property**". 
**On hover**, I want to **expend the width** (From 50% to 75%) of the hovered div. 
I managed to make it work with the left div but not with the right div. 
How ? Why? Been tying a lot of things without success.

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="size" id="proprety">
    <h1>Propreties</h1>
    <p>The best of the proprety</p>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="land">
    <h1>Land</h1>
    <p>The best of the proprety</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

.size{
height:600px;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: width .2s;
float:left;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.borders{
padding:10%;
}

#proprety{
background-image:url(proprety.jpg);
width:50%;

}

#land{
background-image:url(land.jpg);
-webkit-transition: width .2s;
width:50%;
}

#proprety:hover{
width:75%;
}

#proprety:hover + #land{
width:25%;
}


#land:hover{
width:75%;
}

#land:hover + #proprety{
width:25%;
}
```

So far:
https://jsfiddle.net/Chloe75/akbqxc2v/

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: the element+element selector only works for forward elements, and not backwards like you used in

```
#land:hover + #proprety{
    width:25%;
}
```

Since `#land` comes after `#proprety`, it won't work like you want it to.

You can emulate this using flexbox like:

```css
.size{
 height:200px;
 overflow:hidden;
 -webkit-transition: width .2s;
 float:left;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.borders{
 padding:10%;
}

#proprety{
  background-color:blue; 
  width:50%; 
}

#land{
 background-color:green;
 width:50%;
}

#proprety:hover, #land:hover{
 width:75%;
}

div.container-fluid {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="size" id="proprety">
    <h1>Propreties</h1>
    <p>The best of the proprety</p>
  </div>
  <div class="size" id="land">
    <h1>Land</h1>
    <p>The best of the proprety</p>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh wow dunno how to thanks you. Work absolutely perfectly! I really need to learn more about flex property. Thank you and have a wonderful day!

Comment: Glad to help you. If the answer worked for you could you please mark it as correct? Thanks.